# hex viewer/editor GUI component for Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, components, hex

I'm looking for a decent hex viewer (read-only; I don't need an editor) GUI component that I can use within my Swing GUI. Is there anything out there? I suppose I could write my own, but am hoping to avoid doing this. (also it would be nice to be able to render certain bytes as colorized/bold to highlight particular bytes in question.)

edit: this is for displaying the contents of a ByteBuffer in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried http://fifesoft.com/#/hexeditor ?

HexEditor is a hex editor component, written in Swing. Its feature set includes:

Cut, copy, paste, delete
Undo/redo
ASCII view of file content
Input validation

It is released under a BSD-style license.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Hex Editor Component](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhecomponent/). It's old but working fine

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it... but it's GPL and that's not permissible in my application.

Comment: well ... look at the code, get an idea on how it is designed, then write your own :P

Answer (score 1):

I am currently developing

http://hexedit-lib.sourceforge.net/

the component itself is somehow mature, but some features are still missing (like Copy/Cut/Paste). There is a GUI as well which provides a working HexEditor which shows as well how to use. Work in progress ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal component / editor written in Swing under Apache License V2.

http://deltahex.exbin.org

It should be usable as viewer component too and you should be able to colorize characters overriding painter with your custom implementation.